# angular cli must use import to load ES module

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

So i have installed angular with `npm install -g @angular/cli` and updated npm, but if i try to run `ng`in terminal i get this output. I dont want to edit these files before im sure im not screwing them up

```
Unknown error: Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/is-promise/index.js 
require() of ES modules is not supported. 
require() of /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/is promise/index.js from /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/run-async/index.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules. 
Instead rename /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/is-promise/index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/is-promise/package.json.
```

Comment: Try updating angular cli, this was due to a dependency on is-promise https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17549

Comment: An advice, do not install Angular CLI globally, use `npx` to run your commands.


Example: `npx ng g application MyApplication`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

removed "type": "module" from /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/is-promise/package.json